# Two Android apps with ALMOST the same content

Tags: android

Can I upload two Android applications to the Play Store with the same layouts and java code, but different name and Sqlite data?

I'm making two apps about a mini-wiki of two versions of a MMORPG Game.

Comment: Nothing forbides you to do that, there are lot of generic apps out there that just change name and logo.

Comment: The only thing that really needs to be different is the package name. Like `com.foo.app.premium` vs `com.foo.app.free`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Yes, you can.** However, you should make sure these are two separate projects with different package names.

Answer (score 1):

I worked for a company that had over 6,000 apps that were basically just reskins of one single app. It made sense in that case, the company wasn't just trying to game the system, but it shows that you can do it without any issues.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can upload as long as you have two different applications with the different package names.